# Flex: Handle a multi-char comment-like delimiter

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm trying to parse a language which has a certain "escape sequence" using flex/bison. Currently, I'm stuck defining the lexer. It's easiest to explain by example:

```
Text    --> {if} test {literal} text 43.21 {if} foo {/literal} {if}
            ---- ---- --------- ------------------- ---------- ----   etc.
Desired -->  IF  TEXT (ignore)         TEXT          (ignore)   IF
  Token
```

As you can see, the language contains some terminal symbols such as `IF` or `TEXT`, which are rather straight-forward.
However, everything between `{literal}` and `{/literal}` is a `TEXT`, even if it contains strings which would otherwise be special tokens.

The best I could come up with for a lexer so far is this, which uses [Start Conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) for jumping between the different states: If it encounteres a `{literal}`, it activates the `LITERAL` rules.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#define YY_DECL int yylex()
%}
%x LITERAL
%%
[^{]+                 {printf("TEXT: %s\n", yytext);}
"{if}"                {printf("IF\n");}
"{literal}"           {BEGIN(LITERAL);}
<LITERAL>[^{]+        {printf("TEXT: %s\n", yytext);}
<LITERAL>"{"          {printf("TEXT: %s\n", yytext);}
<LITERAL>"{/literal}" {BEGIN(INITIAL);}
%%
main() {yylex();}
```

But how to leave the `LITERAL` state? Using this definition with the example above gives

```
IF
TEXT:  test 
TEXT:  text 43.21 
TEXT: {
TEXT: if} foo 
IF
```

In other words, the `TEXT` token within the `{literal}` tags is split at the `{`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: How should your code handle strings `{literal} "{/literal}" {/literal}`; which of the two appearances of `{/literal}` marks the end of the literal?  To some extent, that's immaterial (you don't have quoted strings in the language shown).  But you'll need to know the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Having a closing tag without an opening tag would be a syntax error.

Comment: OK: I think your problem would be an opening quote without a close quote, but I understand what you mean.  I'm looking at code to see what I do with such comments.  The answer is "it varies", depending on what else I need to do with the 'comment' — and most often I just delete it.  So I'm not yet sure I have a good answer, nor whether `yymore()` is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text inside `{literal}` is split at `{` because you match `{`; if you don't want the text to be split, you need to use the rules inside the `LITERAL` start condition to *extend* the match, rather than each one creating a new match. This is a fairly common (f)lex idiom, and there is a feature designed specifically for this purpose: `yymore`:

> `yymore()` tells the scanner that the next time it matches a rule, the corresponding token should be appended onto the current value of yytext rather than replacing it.

(from the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-yymore_0028_0029).)

Using that handy feature, we can write:

```
"{literal}"           {BEGIN(LITERAL);}
<LITERAL>[^{]+        {yymore();}
<LITERAL>"{"          {yymore();}
<LITERAL>"{/literal}" {
                        /* Now we have to provide the token, but we've matched
                         * 10 extra characters, the close marker, and so the
                         * token is the text from yytext with length yyleng-10.
                         * Here we just print it out, but normally we'd copy
                         * yytext to a temporary for future processing.
                         * Most compilers will optimize out the call to strlen.
                         */
                        BEGIN(INITIAL);
                        printf("TEXT: %.*s\n",
                               (int)(yyleng - strlen("{/literal}")),
                               yytext);
                      }
```

The above assumes that the `LITERAL` state is literally literal :), that is, that it is only terminated with the `{/literal}` tag and that the `{/literal}` tag is always recognized, regardless of context. However, it's not dependent on that; you could do more complex token recognition inside the literal scan, as long as you always use `yymore()` in every action except the action for the closing tag.

If my assumption is correct, another solution is available: simply match the entire literal with a regular expression. It would be easier to write the regular expression with non-greedy matches (or even directly as a finite state machine), but unfortunately flex doesn't implement those, so it has to be done the long way, and it is truly long. Fortunately, the end marker starts with a character which is not contained inside the end-marker, so the regular expression can be generated mechanically fairly easily. Here, I've used flex definitions to avoid a really long line, and to make the pattern a little more apparent:

```
l1             [{]
l2          "/"[{]
l3         "/l"[{]
l4        "/li"[{]
l5       "/lit"[{]
l6      "/lite"[{]
l7     "/liter"[{]
l8    "/litera"[{]
l9   "/literal"[{]
loop [{](l1|l2|l3|l4|l5|l6|l7|l8|l9)*

n1             [^{/]
n2          "/"[^{l]
n3         "/l"[^{i]
n4        "/li"[^{t]
n5       "/lit"[^{e]
n6      "/lite"[^{r]
n7     "/liter"[^{a]
n8    "/litera"[^{l]
n9   "/literal"[^{}]
next n1|n2|n3|n4|n5|n6|n7|n8|n9

prefix  "{literal}"
middle  ([^{]|{loop}{next})*
suffix  {loop}"/literal}"

literal {prefix}{middle}{suffix}
```

%%

```
{literal}  {
              /* The token includes both the {literal} opener and
               * the {/literal} closer, so we need to get rid of
               * both of them.
               */ 
              printf("TEXT: %.*s\n",
                     (int)(yyleng - strlen("{literal}") - strlen("{/literal}")),
                     yytext + strlen("{literal}"));
           }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I think your first solution will suffice, though ;)